# ExpressionEngine 1.6 x Nginx

Tags: ee1, server, nginx

So Im sticking with EE1 but I wanted to know if anyone has updated or has any information on updating EE1 to nginx from apache?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Nginx page for ExpressionEngine](http://wiki.nginx.org/ExpressionEngine) has sample configs, that should work for EE 1.6.x. And, here are more examples in an [Archived EE Forum Thread on Nginx](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/92987/). And, more good info is available in this [Current EE Forum Thread on Nginx](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/213024/).

I think that any info you find on the web about using Nginx with EE should be applicable to EE 1, even if the example uses EE 2. From the point of view of the web server (Apache or Nginx), there aren't any significant differences between EE 1 and EE 2. In both EE 1 & 2, you need to redirect all requests to the index.php file, except for requests to actual files and folders.